# Why implicit object has precedence over val in Scala 2.13-M5?

Tags: scala, resolution, implicit, scala-2.13

I'm wondering if this is a bug or an expected behaviour in Scala 2.13-M5.

Following snippet compiles and outputs "object in package object":

```
package object test {
  implicit val a: TS = new TS("val in package object")
  implicit object b extends TS("object in package object")
}

package test {
  class TS(override val toString: String)

  class Inner {
    implicit val f: TS = new TS("val in inner class")
    val resolve = implicitly[TS]
  }
  object Test extends App {
    println(new Inner().resolve)
  }
}
```

With commented out third line `implicit object b extends TS("object in package object"` there is an ambiguous implicit compile error which is what I would expect in first case as well:

```
Error:(11, 29) ambiguous implicit values:
 both value a in package test of type => test.TS
 and value f in class Inner of type => test.TS
 match expected type test.TS
    val resolve = implicitly[TS]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `a`, `b` and `f` all seem to be eligible implicit values. As the [FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) says (emphasis mine):

> [...] this entails selecting a **narrower type** or a value defined in a subclass relative to other eligible values

therefore, the object `b` is selected, because `b.type` is a strict subtype of `TS`.

---

Here is another example that demonstrates the same behavior, but without packages or objects:

```
case class TS(str: String)

object test {
  implicit val a: TS = new TS("val in package object")
  // implicit object b extends TS("object in package object")
  class MoreSpecial() extends TS("I'm special")
  implicit val s: MoreSpecial = new MoreSpecial()

  class TS(override val toString: String)

  class Inner {
    implicit val f: TS = new TS("val in inner class")
    val resolve = implicitly[TS]
  }
  object Test {
    def run(): Unit = {
      println(new Inner().resolve)
    }
  }
}

test.Test.run()
```

it will print `"I'm special"`, because the instance of class `MoreSpecial` thinks that it's the most specific one, simply because its type `MoreSpecial` is a strict subtype of `TS`.

Moreover,

- if you uncomment the `b` line, it gives ambiguous implicits error (`b: b.type <: TS` conflicts with `s: MoreSpecial <: TS`)
- if you comment the `s` line, it also gives ambiguous implicits error (`a: TS` conflicts with `f: TS`)
- only if ((`s` is commented) XOR (`b` is commented)), then it compiles (both `b: b.type` and `s: MoreSpecial` win over `a: TS` and `f: TS`)

That's all as expected. This holds for 2.12.6, so it doesn't seem specific to 2.13-Mx.

Comment: Nice, basically static overloading rules in play. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Great explanation. Is there a motivation for preferring narrower types?

Comment: @Owen Afair, the language designers needed *some* way to order the implicits from less specific to more specific. Giving a value with the widest supertype of the type for which you're currently searching an implicit value doesn't seem to make any sense: an implicit `Any` defined anywhere would beat everything else. So they took the subtyping relation. This choice sometimes leads to counter-intuitive behavior when combined with variance annotations, though...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Well, an implicit `Any` would likely not satisfy the implicit bounds. An implicit `Nothing` would, though, and it would also beat everything under the narrowest rule...

Comment: @Owen yeah, I guess the reasoning went somehow along those lines: a value of type `Any` would not be substitutable where a value of some other type `T` is needed... I don't remember the exact arguments for and against every proposed notion of "specificity", if you want, you can google for "scala, contravariance, implicits", and you'll probably find quite a few heated debates from few years ago. It seems, later this whole problem area has been deemphasized, and people simply found some other topics to disagree on...

Comment: You can also make it ambiguous by switching the order of the package object and the package. Future Scala will require type for implicit, so implicit object is already discouraged.